# Создать запрос для базы MYSQL имея готовую бд

Tags: mysql

Есть огромная бд с кучей таблиц. Мне нужно составить sql запрос, чтобы создать точно такую же бд. 
 Есть ли готовая методика для таких целей или придется самому создавать запрос, исследуя каждую таблицу. 
База данных имеет 40 таблиц и много полей, поэтому проблематично составить 1 запрос для такой бд вручную.

Comment: создать dump базы с расширениям sql при помощи утилиты mysqldump. Он тебе создаст файл с кучей запросов.

Comment: [Using mysqldump for Backups](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-mysqldump.html). Бэкап текущей БД и восстановление на новом месте.